# Why is my LINQ statement returning IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, iqueryable

I have two very similar methods:

```
public IQueryable<User> Find(Func<User, bool> exp)
{
    return db.Users.Where(exp);
}

public IQueryable<User> All()
{
    return db.Users.Where(x => !x.deleted);
}
```

The top one, will not compile, saying it returns IEnumerable rather than IQueryable.

Why is this?

Also, I am aware I can add "AsQueryable()" on the end and it will work. What difference does that make though? Any performance hits? I understand that IQueryable has deferred execution and such, will I still get this benefit?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`Enumerable.Where` takes `Func<T, bool>`.

`Queryable.Where` takes `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`.

You're calling Where with a `Func<T, bool>`, therefore only the `Enumerable.Where` call is applicable, and that returns `IEnumerable<T>`.

Change your method to:

```
public IQueryable<User> Find(Expression<Func<User, bool>> exp)
{
    return db.Users.Where(exp);
}
```

and it should be okay. Basically you want to pass in an expression tree instead of a delegate, so that the expression can be converted to SQL.